# Biased spectrum from increased lmax in function synfast of healpy

Tags: python, healpy

I played recently with the function `synfast` from healpy using python. More particularly I played with its parameter *lmax* which sets the maximum mode to be computed (default: lmax = 3*nside-1). I also used the `ud_grade` function as you will see.

I explored several cases where I generated very simple maps with `synfast` from a flat spectra equal to unity (in temperature TT and polarisation EE and BB). Then computed back the spectra from those maps using `anafast`. I found that we do not recover the initial input spectrum in all cases as shown on the following plot.

In all those cases, I set the *pixwin* argument of `synfast` to *True*, then corrected the output signal of `anafast` using the function `pixwin(nside=128)`.

- Dashed grey : input spectrum model
- Blue : (normal default case) `synfast(nside=128, lmax=3*128-1)` => `anafast(lmax=3*128-1)`
- Green : `synfast(nside=256, lmax=3*256-1)` => `ud_grade(256->128)` => `anafast(lmax=3*128-1)`
- Magenta : `synfast(nside=256, lmax=3*128-1 )` => `ud_grade(256->128)` => `anafast(lmax=3*128-1)`
- Red : `synfast(nside=128, lmax=4*128-1 )` => `anafast(lmax=3*128-1)`
- Cyan : `synfast(nside=128, lmax=10*128-1 )` => `anafast(lmax=3*128-1)`

[Plot : spectra estimations from different kind of map using syfast, ud_grade and anafast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr3MS.jpg)

- As you can see, I get biased spectra in most cases.
- Even the normal case (blue) is slightly bias downward for high modes. This is apparently normal, since healpy does not handle very well spectrum estimation for modes > 2*nside-1.
- Results are the same for temperature an polarisation spectra (TT, EE and BB).
- As you see, the cases lmax=4*128-1 and lmax=10*128-1 give same results. This comes from `synfast` that does not allows *lmax* to go higher than 4*128-1, and sets lmax=4*128-1 even if we ask for higher *lmax*.

Does somebody have an explanation for this behaviour ?

And how to recover the initial input spectrum ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected impact of ud_grade, it is a destructive operation, you wipe out signal over some scale and in fact you recover a bias which is consistent with white noise.